# Global ng-options doesn't display for some <select>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I call the select in my html like that :

```
<form class="form-inline col-sm-6" ng-repeat="critere in criteres | orderBy:'data'">
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">{{critere.lib}}</label>
   <select ng-if="critere.type=='select'" ng-model="critere.value" ng-options="item.id as item.libelle for item in ref[critere.data+'s']" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is where the "criteres" are managed in angular :

```
$scope.allcriteres=$scope.allparams.filter(function (param) {
    return (angular.isDefined(param.data));
});
```

The array `$scope.allparams` is like this :

```
$scope.allparams=[
            {'tab':'ADH', 'title':'Adhérent'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'civilite', 'lib':'Civilité', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'nom', 'lib':'Nom', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'prenom', 'lib':'Prénom', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'dateNaissance', 'lib':'Date de naissance', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'nationalite', 'lib':'Nationalité', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'statut', 'lib':'Statut', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'lieuNaissance', 'lib':'Lieu de Naissance', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'dateCertificatMedical', 'lib':'Date Certificat Médical', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'adresse1', 'lib':'Adresse 1', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'adresse2', 'lib':'Adresse 2', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'codePostal', 'lib':'Code Postal', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'ville', 'lib':'Ville', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'pays', 'lib':'Pays', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'adresseEtiquette', 'lib':'Adresse Etiquette', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'dateInscription', 'lib':'Date Inscription', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'dateCarteAdherent', 'lib':'Date Carte Adhérent', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'email', 'lib':'Email', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'telephone', 'lib':'Téléphone', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'portable', 'lib':'Portable', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'IBAN', 'lib':'IBAN', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'tailleHaut', 'lib':'Taille Haut', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'tailleBas', 'lib':'Taille Bas', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'dateDroitImage', 'lib':'Droit Image', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'ADH', 'data':'refusDroitImage', 'lib':'Refus Droit Image', 'type':'checkbox'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'title':'Détail comptable'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'saison', 'lib':'Saison', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'activite', 'lib':'Activité', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'prix', 'lib':'Prix', 'type':'currency'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'affectation', 'lib':'Affectation', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'moyenPaiement', 'lib':'Moyen de Paiement', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'localisation', 'lib':'Localisation', 'type':'select'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'dateCheque', 'lib':'Date Chèque', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'dateEcheance', 'lib':'Date Echéance', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'banque', 'lib':'Banque', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'numCheque', 'lib':'Numéro de Chèque', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'dateLicence', 'lib':'Date Licence', 'type':'date'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'licence', 'lib':'Licence', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'DET', 'data':'libelle', 'lib':'Libelle', 'type':'text'},
            {'tab':'AFF', 'data':'codeComptable', 'lib':'Code Comptable', 'type':'text'}

        ];
        var order=0;
        $scope.allparams.forEach(function(param){
            if (param.tab=='adh') param.ordersource=1; else param.ordersource=2;
            param.order=order;
            order++;
            param.added=false;
        });

        if(exportService.getStockParams()!=undefined){
            $scope.allparams = exportService.getStockParams();
        }
        // récupération des valeurs de référence pour les listes
        var promises = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.refs, function (ref) {
            promises[ref.type] = refService.getRefs(ref.type);
        });
        $q.all(promises).then(function (responses) {
            $scope.ref={};
            angular.forEach(responses, function (response, type) {
                $scope.ref[type]=response.data;
                console.log($scope.ref);
            });

        });
```

The selects with no options showing are :

- adresseEtiquette
- tailleHaut
- tailleBas
- moyenPaiement

I can't figure why those. The `console.log`, in the end of the last part of code I put, shows that `$scope.ref` has all the options (meaning the php does his job by getting them from the db. So no need to show this part). But they are not displayed. I really don't get why those in particular.

I thought of something in the html. Like a condition preventing some to show up. But I don't know where.

I someone figured and could explain that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I got the answer. That was tricky af.

As you can see in the html :

```
<select ng-if="critere.type=='select'" ng-model="critere.value" ng-options="item.id as item.libelle for item in ref[critere.data+'s']" class="form-control"></select>
```

There is `ref[critere.data+'s']`
That **"s"** is here for a reason. (I'll explain below)

In the array, every select is following this syntax :

```
{'tab':'TAB', 'data':'dataname', 'lib':'Libelle', 'type':'select'}
```

The `data` is here for 2 things :

1. The name of the data in the database `TAB` (as a foreign key)
2. The name of the database with the values for the data in the first point.

What is important is that the database name as an "s" and not the data. But with that apart it's the same word.

**So** : The code was made in the case that the name of the data as a foreign key is the same than the database name but without a **"s"** !!

@yassine-badache was really close. Because the problem was the data. The foreign key is good, but the database is not the foreign key with a **"s"** in the new data I added  !

So I had to change 2 things :

```
{'tab':'TAB', 'data':'foreignkeyname', 'lib':'Libelle', 'type':'select', 'dataref':'the_database_with_the_"s"'},
```

and

```
<select ng-if="critere.type=='select'" ng-model="critere.value" ng-options="item.id as item.libelle for item in ref[critere.dataref]" class="form-control"></select>
```

**SUCCESS**

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this has any influence, but every entry with `select` as a type which are not showing contains a space character in their `lib` field:

- adresseEtiquette: "Adresse Etiquette"
- tailleHaut: "Taille Haut"
- tailleBas: "Taille Bas"
- moyenPaiement: "Moyen de Paiement"

The other criterias with the `select` option does not. There are high chances that the problem comes from this fact, even if I, too, cannot figure out why. It is the only valid reason I can see, considering the informations you provide.

---

**EDIT**

It changed nothing, but in your `data` field, the values that are not showing off, compared to the others, all have a capital letter. This sounds stupid, but it is still another difference:

- civilite : shows
- nationalite: shows
- status: shows
- adresse**E**tiquette: doesn't show
- taille**H**aut: doesn't show
- taille**B**as: doesn't show
- saison: shows
- activite: shows
- affectation: shows
- moyen**P**aiement: doesn't show
- localisation: shows

Your filter function maybe has a problem with that, I do not know exactly. I'm just making assumptions.

Comment: That has nothing to do ^^ It's only what is showing when you choose one of those `params`. I tried without space anyway, but it does nothing, just changed the text of the selected `critere`. But that's impressive you saw that

Comment: I will edit the question, I saw something similar xD

Comment: Hum... That's interesting... But I doubt it, that's how I call those data **everywhere** in my entire code. But still more legit than the spaces ^^ I'll still investigate that way, while that's the only one I got